# OCF Antenna Feed Line

Tags: antenna, antenna-system

I built a OCF HF antenna. The feed line contains a 4:1 balun and a line insolator (choke) per instructions. When checking the radio end of the coax, I get a "grounded" response between the inner wire and outer mesh. Is this a correct circumstance?

Comment: It's quite possibly normal, but we need more information to be sure. Please [edit your question](http://ham.stackexchange.com/posts/5725/edit) to specify these two things: (1) Show the instructions you followed. At least the designs of the balun and choke. (2) When you say "I get a grounded response", what test equipment are you using (multimeter? antenna analyzer?) to make that measurement?